# Nginx not redirecting non www version correctly

Tags: nginx, redirect, http, 301-redirect

the http version is handle by nginx and the https is handle by apache.

Now my issue is that for example when u type https://sitename.com/contact/ it works fine but when u type http://sitename.com/contact/ is redirecting to the homepage https://www.sitename.com

Above is my nginx config.

```
server {

        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name sitename.com www.sitename.com;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

         }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }



    listen 80; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the nginx.conf file was missing this

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any kind of redirect or rewrite in that config at all.

Something like the following should work:

```
server {
server_name www.example.com;
return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;}
```

I borrowed this from [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-centos-7) Digital Ocean page.

Comment: looks like is not working

Comment: @JackDuldi Can you provide more details regarding it not working? i.e. what did you change your config to? What was the behaviour once you changed the config?
Is there any helpful info in the NginX logs that might help out here?

Comment: well i added this to /etc/nginx/default.conf return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;} and still nothing its redirecting the same

Comment: @JackDuldi Could you please update your question to show the change that you have tried.

Comment: I would add a `listen 80 default;` (so this virtual server is selected for unknown server names and no server name) and add `example.com` to the server names (`server_name example.com www.example.com`). @JakeInTheMiddle, there is a typo in the `return` directive: should be `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;`, because the variable `$scheme` contains `http`, not `https`.